# Why is the overload signature not compatible with the implementation signature when an optional parameter is a string?

Tags: typescript, overloading

I have the following function and its overloads:

```js
export function doAction(type: Type, mode: 'horizontal'): string;

export function doAction(type: Type, count2: number): string;

export function doAction(type: Type, count?: number, count2?: number, mode?: string): string {
  return type;
}
```

However, TS is telling me that `TS2394: This overload signature is not compatible with its implementation signature.`, the problem being the `mode` parameter. If I change its type to `number`, it works. I'm baffled as to why this is happening. Any ideas?

---

I've tried changing and swapping parameters around, making them required, etc., just to see how it'd behave. I was expecting it to just work, given it's just a basic overload, and the other, simple types *just work*. I don't see why it being a string creates issues. I even tried to input `mode: string` (so, no value, just a type), and it still refuses to work.

I looked at like 30+ other questions, but none seem to cover this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation expects the second argument to be a `number`; you need to change it to take `number | 'horizontal'`, so that both overloads are expected:

```js
export function doAction(type: Type, count?: number | 'horizontal', count2?: number, mode?: string): string {
  return type;
}
```

Comment: I see. This answers the question, but it's very confusing, and I see I've made a mistake now. Do you have any ideas on how to write this better?

Answer (score 0):

The optional arguments must be in order and the names don't matter.

So here, if you choose number as the second argument (it doesn't matter if it's optional), it will never be a string and therefore will never be compatible with your first overload. Similarly, if you had chosen your second argument as a string in your implementation, it would never be a number, so it's your second overload that would throw an error.
Like typescript say it's no compatible with the implementation.

So if you can modify your implementation like that:

```
export function doAction(type: Type, count?: unknown, count2?: number, mode?: string): string {
  return type;
}
```

This is an example, 'any' or 'number | "horizontal" ' would also work.
Although it makes more sense to me to have it type unknown if you don't know what type it will be and it forces you to check your code properly.